# Can I use an Arduino LCD with my Raspberry Pi?

Tags: wifi, lcd

I have a 16x2 Arduino LCD and I want to make a bitcoin price tracker with it and my Raspberry Pi, can I do it?
[image: Arduino LCD]

Answer (score 1):

Possibly.

The only concern is that all the Pi GPIO are 3V3 whereas Arduino GPIO are typically 5V.

You need to power the device with 5V.

Typically for a signal to be seen as logic 1 rather than logic 0 its voltage must be at least 70% of the supply voltage.  That means you need to supply at least 3V5 from a Pi GPIO which can't be done.

You may get lucky with your device and it may accept the lower Pi voltage as logic 1.

Answer (score 1):

This is **NOT** an "Arduino LCD" - if you search you will find a number of questions about interfacing similar devices to the Pi.

You **CAN** interface to the Pi, however this uses several GPIO pins, and you will need to provide a potentiometer to control the LCD backlight.

A better option is to use a similar devices with an I²C interface which only uses 2 GPIO pins, and includes a potentiometer.